# Solr Container

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty

What is better container for SOLR: Tomcat or Jetty

Comment: There are also other Servlet Containers. In the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Solr_Comes_with_Jetty.2C_is_Jetty_the_recommended_Servlet_Container_to_use_when_running_Solr.3F) is explained why Jetty comes with the Solr example and there are also [configurations](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Servlet_Container_or_Environment_Specific_Tips) of other containers described on the Solr wiki.

Comment: This question is pretty much deprecated now that Solr 5 is a stand alone application that doesn't require external servlet container at all.

Answer (score 7):

Jetty is bundled with Solr due to it's [size](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Solr_Comes_with_Jetty.2C_is_Jetty_the_recommended_Servlet_Container_to_use_when_running_Solr.3F):

> The Solr example app has Jetty in it just because at the time we set
>   it up, Jetty was the simplest/smallest servlet container we found that
>   could be run easily in a cross platform way (ie: "java -jar
>   start.jar"). That does not imply that Solr runs better under Jetty, or
>   that Jetty is only good enough for demos -- it's just that Jetty made
>   our demo setup easier.
>
> Users should decide for themselves which Servlet Container they
>   consider the easiest/best for their use cases based on their
>   needs/experience. For high traffic scenarios, investing time for
>   tuning the servlet container can often make a big difference.

I have been running Solr with Jetty for few small sites for months and had no problems.

My vote goes for Jetty.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat. We had some large documents truncated and dropped using Jetty.

Answer (score 3):

> It runs in a Java servlet container such as Tomcat.

It shouldn't matter since they are both servlet containers. Use whatever you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

I used Solr with Tomcat6 with no problems.

The fact that Solr and Tomcat are both Apache products and still Solr comes with lightweight Jetty included must mean something.

Here are few Tomcat vs Jetty links:
http://www.slideshare.net/noriaki/jetty-vs-tomcat
http://www.asjava.com/jetty/jetty-vs-tomcat-performance-comparison/

From the Jetty evangelist standpoint:
http://www.webtide.com/choose/jetty.jsp

Answer (score 2):

I mostly used jetty while rapid prototyping with Solr. Because Jetty is packaged with Solr, it was very convenient to use. However, we use Tomcat6 in production. It was easy to transition.

I would say go with what your most comfortable with initially.

According to the Solr Wiki:
"For non-trivial installations, JettyPlus is recommended."
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty

Answer (score 2):

jetty has some issues with unicode text (or at least had when I was working on it the last time). So if you have non english documents to index, your only choice is Tomcat. Also, if you are looking at running solr on 64bit Windows Server - you can get a 64-bit Tomcat but I don't think there is a 64-bit Jetty server available.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it especially matters, they'll both work.

If you're using either of them already, stick with it.

If not... well, given that [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) are both Apache projects, it seems simpler to also go with [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

If you do want to go with [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) though, [you can](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty).

Answer (score 0):

used with tomcat6 no problem, you will need to reload tomcat with each schema change however

Comment: That's certainly not true unless you meant reloading Solr and not restarting tomcat service. And on Jetty you'd need to reload Solr on schema change as well.