# Failed to query Solr using '*:*': [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, django-haystack

Tried to integrate haystack 2.0.0-beta - solr with my django  project for full text search, when i run the following

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
al = SearchQuerySet().all()
```

got an error

```
Failed to query Solr using '*:*': [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How can i solve this issue?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't look to be running and you haven't given any details so:

Solr is a standalone process that needs to be started manually. Furthermore, [it needs a servlet container to run within](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Solr_Comes_with_Jetty.2C_is_Jetty_the_recommended_Servlet_Container_to_use_when_running_Solr.3F), normally `jetty` or `tomcat` which are both java based (discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602857/solr-container) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/224396/apache2-solr-tomcat-or-jetty)). Depending on your machine, you need to install **and start** these before you get started with python or Django. If you are debian you can most likely do `apt-get install solr-jetty` and voila.

Once solr is installed, you need the bindings for python `pysolr` - `pip install pysolr` and django haystack `pip install haystack==2.0`.

There is a tutorial in the [haystack documentation here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#solr), as well as a good blog [post here](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/django-haystack-solr-setup-guide/) about installing, starting and configuring the combination of solr, jetty, python and django.